# Elementary number theory(index)

Tags: elementary-number-theory

Is it a definition that Let r be a fixed primitive root of n. suppose $gcd(a,n)=1$.
Then $ind_r a=k$ where$ a \equiv r^k$ (mod n) and $
 1<=k<=phi(n)$?

The reason I question it is my professor wrote not $ind_r a=k$ but $ind(a)=k$.
So I'm confused when solving questions.

Comment: In what context was "$\mathrm{ind}(a) = k$" used?  The base may have been obvious from context.

Comment: um... only Blackboard!! and he didnt solve any examples:(